# How to record a time varied data in Excel without VBA?

Tags: excel

For example, I have a RTS data source providing a number changes from time to time (Say, the price of a stock). So I got a number in a cell and it changes. How can I create a table that records every number shown (i.e. insert a new row when the number changes)? I know how to do it with VBA, but is is possible to do it without VBA (perhaps with some new feature in the latest version)?

Comment: What you want is basicaly a log, with all historical values of the number?

Comment: Yes, but this log should be shown as table in sheet.

Comment: There's no automated way to do this with just formulas, you need to use VBA.